# What is an "ERM rule" in Understanding Machine Learning by Shalev-Shwartz and Ben-David?

Tags: machine-learning, pac-learning

I am reading "Understanding Machine Learning" book by Shalev-Shwartz and Ben-David.
On page 48, theorem 6.7 (The fundamental theorem of statistical learning, FTSL) says: Let $H$ be a hypothesis class... the following properties are equivalent... 4. $H$ is PAC learnable. 5.  Any ERM rule is a successful PAC learner for $H$.

I could not find the definition of ERM rule in this book or anywhere. What is it?

It can not be any algorithm which minimizes empiric risk, can it?

What are the conditions on the algorithm to find the PAC solution?

Comment: Empirical risk minimization ?

Comment: @RobertLong Yes, ERM is empirical risk minimization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [section 6.4](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf#section.183) of *Understanding Machine Learning* by Shai Shalev-Shwartz and Shai Ben-David, it is written

> Theorem 6.7 (The Fundamental Theorem of Statistical Learning) Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a hypothesis class of functions from a domain $\mathcal{X}$ to $\{0,1\}$ and let the loss function be the $0 - 1$ loss. Then, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\mathcal{H}$ has the uniform convergence property.
> 2. Any ERM rule is a successful agnostic PAC learner for $\mathcal{H}$.
> 3. $\mathcal{H}$ is agnostic PAC learnable.
> 4. $\mathcal{H}$ is PAC learnable.
> 5. Any ERM rule is a successful PAC learner for $\mathcal{H}$.
> 6. $\mathcal{H}$ has a finite VC-dimension.

When the authors write "the following are equivalent", what they mean is
$$
\text{statement 1} \implies \text{statement 2} \implies \text{statement 3} \implies \text{statement 4} \implies \text{statement 5} \implies \text{statement 6} \implies \text{statement 1}
$$

So, if statement 1 is true, then statement 2 is true, and if statement 2 is true, then statement 3 is true, and so on, until we form a loop back to statement 1. After listing these statements, the authors then write

> The proof of the theorem is given in the next section.

In [section 6.5](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf#section.196), it is written

> We have already seen that $1 \implies 2$ in Chapter 4. The implications $2 \implies 3$ and $3 \implies 4$ are trivial and so is $2 \implies 5$. The implications $4 \implies 6$ and $5 \implies 6$ follow from the No-Free-Lunch theorem.

---

#### Response to first comment

> You only write what is obvious. So, what is ERM rule? What is the definition of ERM rule?

Unfortunately, it seems that the wording of Theorem 6.7 is a bit vague. In [section 8.2](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf#section.303), the authors write

> Given a hypothesis class, $\mathcal{H}$, a domain set $Z$, and a loss function $\ell$, the corresponding $\text{ERM}_{\mathcal{H}}$ rule can be defined as follows:
>
> On a finite input sample $S \in Z^m$, output some $h \in \mathcal{H}$ that minimizes the empirical loss
> $$
> L_S(h) = \frac{1}{|S|} \sum_{z \in S} \ell (h,z)
> $$

Therefore, every ERM rule is dependent on four choices:

- the hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$,
- the domain set $Z$,
- the finite input sample $S \in Z^m$ (or "training dataset"), and
- the loss function $\ell$

In theorem 6.7, it is written

> ...Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a hypothesis class of functions from a domain $\mathcal{X}$ to $\{0,1\}$ and let the loss function be the $0 - 1$ loss...

which means that the choices of the hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$, the domain set $Z$, and the loss function $\ell$ have already been made. This leaves the choice of the finite input sample (training dataset) $S \in Z^m$. This suggests that when the authors write in Theorem 6.7

> Any ERM rule...

What they mean is

> For any finite input sample (training dataset) $S \in Z^m$, the ERM rule...

#### Response to second comment

> For example. An algorithm picks 2 random functions from the class $H$ and selects one with the lowest empirical risk. This is an ERM algorithm. Will this algorithm be a successful PAC learner for $H$ when $H$ is PAC learnable?

Yes, assuming that you have made your choice of the finite input sample (training dataset) $S \in Z^m$, this is just
$$
\text{statement 4} \implies \text{statement 5}
$$
in theorem 6.7.

#### Response to third comment

> The section 4,2 has only two statements. One is Hoeffding inequality, another is about a finite class of functions. This one states, in particularly, that "The class is agnostically PAC learnable using the ERM algorithm". But it does not specify anything about "the ERM algorithm" and there is no proof that it will work with any ERM algorithm.

I think section 4.2 complements section 4.1, so see section 4.1 as well. Note that in my original answer, I wrote

> [Section 4.2](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf#section.124) **seems** to be what the authors are referring to here.

which means that I wasn't sure if section 4.2 is what they were referring to. Regardless, I've removed this statement from my original answer.

#### Response to fourth comment

> If ERM rule is a rule which finds a hypothesis with minimum ER in the class $H$, then such an algorithm may not even exist for infinite classes. What does the FTSL say then? If there are no algorithms to find absolute minimum of ER every time, the class of function is not PAC learnable then?

I am not sure what you mean by "infinite classes" here. If you mean that $\mathcal{H}$ is infinite in size, then we may not be interested in infinitely sized hypothesis classes anyway. In [section 2.3](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf#section.53), the authors write

> We have just demonstrated that the ERM rule might lead to overfitting. Rather than giving up on the ERM paradigm, we will look for ways to rectify it. We will search for conditions under which there is a guarantee that ERM does not overfit, namely, conditions under which when the ERM predictor has good performance with respect to the training data, it is also highly likely to perform well over the underlying data distribution.

and in section 2.3.1, the authors write

> The simplest type of restriction on a class is imposing an upper bound on its size (that is, the number of predictors $h$ in $\mathcal{H}$). In this section, we show that if $\mathcal{H}$ is a finite class then $\text{ERM}_{\mathcal{H}}$ will not overfit, provided it is based on a sufficiently large training sample (this size requirement will depend on the size of $\mathcal{H}$).

Comment: You only write what is obvious. So, what is ERM rule? What is the definition of ERM rule?

Comment: For example. An algorithm picks 2 random functions from the class $H$ and selects one with the lowest empirical risk. This is an ERM algorithm. Will this algorithm be a successful PAC learner for $H$ when $H$ is PAC learnable?

Comment: The section 4,2 has only two statements. One is Hoeffding inequality, another is about a finite class of functions. This one states, in particularly, that "The class is agnostically PAC learnable using the ERM algorithm". But it does not specify anything about "the ERM algorithm" and there is no proof that it will work with any ERM algorithm.

Comment: If ERM rule is a rule which finds a hypothesis with minimum ER in the class $H$, then such an algorithm may not even exist for infinite classes. What does the FTSL say then? If there are no algorithms to find absolute minimum of ER every time, the class of function is not PAC learnable then?

Comment: @Marina I've responded to your comments at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thank you, very much, for your answer. The most important here is the ERM$_H$ rule, indeed, finds a hypothesis with minimal empirical risk.

Comment: We are, of course, interested in infinite classes of functions. For example, class of linear functions is infinite, and we often search for linear solutions.

Comment: So, the algorithm I proposed is NOT an ERM$_H$ rule, because it does not find the function in the class with the minimal empirical loss.  It only finds a hypothesis with minimal loss among too random hypotheses.

Comment: @Marina while the class of linear functions may be infinite, it is smaller than the class of both linear and non-linear functions. In other words, some infinities are smaller than others. This would suggest that the class of linear functions is "finite" in relation the class of linear and non-linear functions, even though it is individually infinite. This is discussed in detail in section 2.3.

Comment: The theorem talks about finite VC dimension. Class of linear functions has finite VC dimension. Class of all polynomials have infinite VC-dimension. They say, if the VC dimension of the class is finite, then it is PAC learnable. This is equivalent to the fact that every ERM$_H$ rule (if it exists) is successful PAC learner. But it does not mean ERM$_H$ rule exists, as I understand.

Comment: I found the earliest mention of ERM rule. On the pages 36-37 they say "ERM$_H$ learner uses ERM rule to chose predictor $h \in H$ with the lowest possible error over $S$: $$\text{ERM}_H(S) \in \arg\min_{h \in H} L_S(h). "$$ I can not find if such a  rule is always possible even with classes with finite VC dimension.

Answer (score 8):

*ERM rule* stands from *Empirical Risk Minimization rule* and it's a *learning rule* that aims to find a hypothesis (or predictor) by minimizing the empirical risk/error. The empirical risk/error is the error the hypothesis (predictor) incurs over the training sample.

ERM rule specifies *what to do* but doesn't specify *how to do it*. There are several ways to **implement** ERM rule depends on specific learning cases, for example, the simple exhaustive search, the least squares, perceptron, etc. All those implementations share a common goal is to minimize the *empirical risk/error*.

Besides ERM rule, there're other learning rules such as Structural Risk Minimization with minimum description length (also mentioned in the book) which doesn't only minimize the empirical risk.

Comment: No one of the rules you mentioned is guaranteed to find a minimum of the empiric risk.

Comment: @Marina, even in the (agnostic) PAC learnable hypothesis class?

Comment: Whole theory assumes that ERM rule finds optimum. When you look closer you see that in this theory the word "algorithm" or "rule" means "function". So, by ERM rule they do not mean any algorithm or rule, but a function which points to a minimum.

Comment: Early on p.16, the word *ERM algorithm* is used. Could you tell which part in the book the (OP mentioned), implies that: "ERM rule they do not mean any algorithm or rule, but a function which points to a minimum"?

Comment: They do not say it explicitly in their book. However, one of the coauthors wrote about it in the paper Sushant Agarwal, Nivasini Ananthakrishnan, Shai Ben-David, and Tosca Lechner. On
learnability with computable learners. Proceedings of Machine Learning Research, 117:1
{ 13, 2020.}

Comment: I wrote about this problem here https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.09500

Comment: @Marina, I've updated the answer. All the information can be found in the book itself and I think, it's pretty clear even though presented somewhat abstract.

Comment: What information you found in the book? What is clear? Did not get it from the answer.

Comment: @Marina, ERM rule is a rule to minimize the empirical error, the empirical error is defined clearly in the book (which I've explicitly rewritten it out in the answer), there're several implementations of this rule. Beside ERM, there are other learning rules. All of those information is included in the book. Do you still find it's unclear?

Comment: Your answer has the definition of what the rule funds. You do not define   a rule which finds this minimum every time.  You have no proof that such an universal rule exists. And it does  not! Read the references I gave you.

Comment: Well, the definition the author gave is well-defined as I see. What may have confused the reader is in 5.) it should be "any ERM learner" instead of "any ERM rule".

Comment: You repeat the same over and over ignoring my answers.  Would you leave me alone?

Comment: @Marina I'd read your reference. If you found the answer is unclear or unhelpful you can downvote it.